# Not all data sent using $http.post angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

why is it that whenever I send data to my server from my mobile application (Ionic Framework) not all data is sent?

```
$http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://remoteserver/data',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                transformRequest: function(obj) {
                    var str = [];
                    for(var p in obj)
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                    return str.join("&");
                },
                data: { image: $scope.imgURI,
                        facebook_id: localStorage.facebook_id,
                        token: localStorage.accessToken,
                        location: localStorage.location,
                        lon: localStorage.longitude,
                        lat: localStorage.latitude
                      }
            }).success(function (suc)
            {
                localStorage.removeItem('longitude');
                localStorage.removeItem('latitude');
                localStorage.removeItem('location');
                alert(JSON.stringify(suc));
            })
            .error(function(err){alert(JSON.stringify(err));});
```

The `location` after is undefined when the server receives it. When in fact, I alert it to check if its not empty. How can I fix this? Of all the data sent to my server, only the location is missing. The location is the reversed geocoding of the latitude and longitude. I just put it in my mobile to reduce the over use of Google API since it is per session basis.

On my server (using laravel) I fetch the sent data using

```
$post->lon = Input::get('lon');
$post->lat = Input::get('lat');
$post->location = Input::get('location');
$post->token= Input::get('token');
$post->facebook_id = Input::get('facebook_id');
```

when I tried to `return Input::all();` I see all the sent data except for the location. It says undefined. The problem is, I can fetch the location once, after I tried again, it returns undefined.

Comment: Why do you think it's angularjs that is to blame? Are you sure the data before you send is what you expect it to be? How do you know that? Have you checked it? How?

Comment: if you dont show the server code how we can know why the server dont send back the location

Comment: Yes, since I use `$post->varible = Input::get('variable');` to get the location and I also use this on others such as latitude and longitude. And I get it all except for the location. BTW, I use laravel in my backend.

Comment: since the error is on the server side please provide more code if you need help

Comment: I already figure this out. Instead of client side, i put it on my server. So my server will be the one accessing the API. though, the downside for this I will have limited API call since, server-side calling is based on IP not like in client side, it is per user session